# Add SKLabelNode programmatically in an exact point

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, swift3

I have this code:

```
var labelNivel = SKLabelNode()

func anadirLabelLevel() {
    labelNivel.name = "labelNivel"
    labelNivel.text = "Level"
    labelNivel.fontSize = 12
    labelNivel.fontColor = UIColor.cyan
    labelNivel.position = CGPoint.zero
    labelNivel.zPosition = 11
    self.addChild(labelNivel)
}
```

which adds a SKLabelNode to point zero of the screen, so I want to add it in the top-left corner of the screen and be able to see it in the correct position on any screen size, so how could I do that?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should base your position making reference to your `anchorPoint` and your label alignment. According to your comments you should remove your code from `sceneDidLoad` and write:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    super.didMove(to: view)
    anadirLabelLevel()
    labelNivel.position = CGPoint(x:self.frame.minX+labelNivel.frame.maxX,y:self.frame.maxY-self.labelNivel.frame.height)
}
```

Comment: aaaaaaall right man we are getting it, what about if I want it in the top-right corner?

Comment: That's simple: change this code with `CGPoint(x:self.frame.maxX-`...leave the rest as is.

Answer (score 0):

What about setting the `position` property of the labelNode?

Take a deeper look at https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/sknode/1483101-position and https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/sknode

Comment: yes position is what I want to work on, but how to make a global position to see it in the same place in all screens?

Answer (score 0):

```
labelNivel.position = CGPointMake(labelNivel.frame.size.width/2 , self.scene.size.height)
```

this will put to top left corner.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133082/discussion-on-answer-by-mkeremkeskin-add-sklabelnode-programmatically-in-an-exac).